# What jobs are available for a person on the autistic spectrum with ADHD?

Tags: air-traffic-control, aircraft-maintenance, medical, career

For a young man who has Autism and ADHD and considered high functioning ( cognitive and processing difficulties but very social ) what types of " hands on " jobs are there for him in the aviation industry?

Comment: Does he like working with his hands and is he good at stuff like building Lego models? (This is not as random as it sounds.)

Comment: [Related](http://aviation.stackexchange.com/q/12747/62). Are you interested specifically in ATC and/or maintenance (based on your tags)?

Comment: This is a very hard to answer question as it very much depends on the person and what you mean by hands on. Can you provide more details? If you want a list of jobs in aviation in general with a brief description of what they involve that might be possible.

Comment: It might be worth talking to your local airport to talk to them about options.

Comment: It is so tempting to reply "management" but I'll refrain.

Comment: pretty much a lot of non-flying jobs come to mind. From cleaning to gate agent to catering to baggage handling. Maybe not the jobs you have in mind. Pilot, controller? Probably not.